# How to add "https://www." into your scraping result with python?

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape a few URLs via python. In particular, I am working on the link to [the Hong Kong electoral platforms.](https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/eng/intro_to_can/A.html) I used the inspect function that chrome provides, and I also used the etree function of lxml on python. I have located the XPath of the text.

The code that I have used is

```
def extract_info_urls(self, response):
        raw_tree = etree.HTML(response)
        platform_urls = raw_tree.xpath('//*[@id="table-district-member"]/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/a/@href|//*[@id="table-district-member"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/a/@href')
        return ["https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/" + platform_url.lstrip("../..") for platform_url in platform_urls]
```

The results look something like this:

```
../../pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html
../../pdf/intro_to_can/A01_2_ENG.html
../../pdf/intro_to_can/A02_1_ENG.html

...
```

With the above being said, my humble question is how can I obtain the full URLs - e.g (https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html)
instead of just URL starting with "../../pdf" in the results.

I appreciate all your help. Looking forward to learning from you all here!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use urljoin():

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin

scraped_url = "https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/eng/intro_to_can/A.html"
pdf_url = "../../pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html"

full_url = urljoin(scraped_url, pdf_url)
```

should give an output of

```
"https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think your method only gives one link at a time, but I am trying to return all of the urls available on the page (e.g 30) at the same time. Any clue?

Comment: same idea as you had before, list comprehension. ```[urljoin(scraped_url, pdf_url) for pdf_url in platform_urls]

Comment: thank you so much for your help! it worked!!